# How convert "blank" to 0 in a card in Power BI with live connection with analysis services?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, analysisservices

i have a dashboard in power bi that take data from analysis services. The problem is that can't show a 0 in a card when there aren't values for this filter. in change show "Blank". Is there a way to show 0 instead of "blank" by some calculation in analysis services?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the blank value using a Conditional Formatting rule on the Call Out Value. The rule is 'if blank', then select the same color as the card or canvas background.

I have created a video tutorial on how to create the conditional rule on the value: https://youtu.be/Xsmbfpa4oCA

Cheers, Bianca

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31733960)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a measure for this.

Measure1= IF(ISBLANK([Measure]),0,[Measure])

Same if its based on a column. Implement the condition inside the measure.Or you can create a new column.

Comment: Where do I run this calculation?

Comment: as I am in a live connection I cannot access the query editor.

Comment: Do you know if you are using tabular? There should be a program ( tabular) where you store all the connections /tables . There you can create the measures.  These tables are coming from the db ( e.g Oracle ) , Usually you push them to tabular and there you create all the measures. Hope this helps !